# started the rails server but localhost page wont load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I started the rails server

```
$ bundle exec rails s -p 3001
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.5 application starting in development on http://localhost:3001
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2016-11-03 19:29:30] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2016-11-03 19:29:30] INFO  ruby 2.2.5 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-darwin15]
[2016-11-03 19:29:30] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=30949 port=3001
```

But when i go to the http://localhost:3001 i get error: This localhost page can’t be found

This is the data i see in terminal after i go on http://locahhost:3001
Any idea what is wrong?

```
{
  "timestamp": "2016-11-03T23:35:40Z",
  "severity": "DEBUG",
  "type": "none",
  "message": "  \u001b[1m\u001b[36mSQL (57.9ms)\u001b[0m  \u001b[1mUSE [peak]\u001b[0m"
}
{
  "timestamp": "2016-11-03T23:35:40Z",
  "severity": "INFO",
  "type": "database.query",
  "request_id": "67b064b7-f6a3-414e-9a39-da4f851fc8dd",
  "connection_id": "70230967245540",
  "event": "SQL",
  "query_id": "a15f740d4daad1a81dbc7e0df1ccf3e5",
  "query": "USE [peak]",
  "duration": "58.3"
}
{
  "timestamp": "2016-11-03T23:35:40Z",
  "severity": "INFO",
  "type": "none",
  "message": "Processing by HomeController#index as HTML"
}
{
  "timestamp": "2016-11-03T23:35:40Z",
  "severity": "INFO",
  "type": "none",
  "message": "  Rendered text template (0.0ms)"
}
{
  "timestamp": "2016-11-03T23:35:40Z",
  "severity": "INFO",
  "type": "view.render",
  "request_id": "67b064b7-f6a3-414e-9a39-da4f851fc8dd",
  "template": "text template",
  "layout": null,
  "duration": "0.4"
}
{
  "timestamp": "2016-11-03T23:35:40Z",
  "severity": "INFO",
  "type": "none",
  "message": "Completed 404 Not Found in 9ms (Views: 8.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)"
}
{
  "timestamp": "2016-11-03T23:35:40Z",
  "severity": "INFO",
  "type": "application.request",
  "request_id": "67b064b7-f6a3-414e-9a39-da4f851fc8dd",
  "method": "GET",
  "status": 404,
  "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36",
  "referrer": null,
  "forwarded_for": null,
  "url_scheme": "http",
  "url_host": "localhost",
  "url_port": "3001",
  "url_path": "/",
  "url_query": null,
  "rails_controller": "home",
  "rails_action": "index",
  "clean_path": "/",
  "remote_ip": "::1",
  "remote_host": "::1",
  "duration": "1108.02",
  "message": "Not Found",
  "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
  "content_type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
}
```

Comment: Your logs include `Completed 404 Not Found in 9ms` it looks like your app is running just fine but there's no route for the path you have provided. What did you expect to see?

Comment: what's in your routes? The last message says that "home#index" is"not found", so routes is a good place to start looking... then... do you have a home controller with an index action (is the next place to look).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Completed 404 Not Found in 9ms (Views: 8.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
> ```

Your server and your app are running fine; your browser is loading the page at http://localhost:3001 perfectly fine.

The problem is that your app is returning a 404 Not Found - in other words, Rails can't match a controller/action to the root route.

Look in your `config/routes.rb` file. You should have a route defined for `root`, such as

```
root :to => 'home#index'
```

If you're accessing a path directly (such as http://localhost:3001/example/path), make sure you have a route defined for that:

```
get 'example/path', :to => 'controller#action'
```

Finally, make sure the relevant controller exists and has a method definiton for the action your route maps to (i.e. for the `root` example, make sure `app/controllers/home_controller.rb` exists and it has an `index` method defined).

Comment: Thanks. I checked the routs.rb and they added a namespace so just had to use namespace in url